# How to cancel process() in SwiftUI from different class

Tags: swiftui, process, observableobject

I am running a binary file using a swift process()  in my DataModel class.  The user can see the process running from the ViewTasks() struct.  How can I give the user the ability to cancel (terminate) the process?

Here is what I have tried:

DataModel class:

```
class DataModel : ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var task = Process()

    func RunTask() {
         // add arguments to task here
         do {
         task.arguments = [args]
         try task.run()
         } catch {}
    }
```

Here is the ViewTask() class:

```
struct ViewTask: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var datamodel: DataModel
    
    var body: some View {
          ///if user presses a cancel button, cancel the task running
          datamodel.task.terminate()
    }
```

This doesn't work because the task can't find the arguments. But when I don't make task an @Published variable, and it only exists locally in that Do loop, it works fine.
Maybe I need to declare/initialize it differently in the datamodel?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `as the task isn't able to run`? you are terminating task

Comment: I edited for clarification.  Basically the task itself stops finding the "arguments" once I try and make it a @Published variable.

Comment: one more question you have declared the task as `@Published` property, what kind of changes are you listening to SwiftUI View for this task property?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out how to have a process (on background or main thread) visible through an observable object.

```
class DataModel : ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var task = Process()

    func RunTask() {
         // add arguments to task here
         do {
             let temptask = Process()
             temptask.arguments = [args]
             // set observable object to this process
             self.task = temptask
             try task.run()
         } catch {}
    }
```

This will allow any other view to call datamodel.task.terminate() and it works just fine.   If the process is in a background thread, simply use DispatchQueue.main.async{self.task = temptask} to set the observable task as the locally made process.

Comment: Suggestion, instead of making `task` as published property, you can add some state property with an enum to manage state of your task